# Permission Issue for laravel APP QUEUE in windows server 2012

Tags: windows, laravel, iis, jobs

We have a **laravel app (Version 5.5*)** deployed in **WIndows Server 2012 R2**. But our development stack is LEMP. Same codebase works fine in development STACK but fails in WINDOWS SERVER.

## **Problem**:

In our App, there is a **REPORT DOWNLOAD queueable job** which reads data from database table and generates an excel file  using **box/spout package(version 2.7)** depending on user input date range (daily,weekly,monthly, etc) .

When running the **queue:work** command from cmd as administrator, 
`$writer->openToFile(‘path/to/file’)` throws an error : **failed to open stream : no such file or directory.**

[See this image for code snippet throwing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLJas.png)

## Solutions I tried:

- Setting right permissions(full control Read & write) for Storage folder of my project (For Users, IIS_IUSRS,IUSR)
- Setting right permissions(full control Read & write) for C:windows\Temp folder (For Users, IIS_IUSRS,IUSR)
- Created symlink for storage folder inside public

## FYI:

- OS: windows server 2012 r2
- PHP: 7.2*
- Laravel: 5.5.*
- box/Spout package: 2.7.*

Comment: Have you tried a different folder?

Comment: Could you share some sample code to reproduce issue? under which identity your application pool is running? try to set the application pool identity network service.

Comment: @thmspl Sorry for the late reply! yes I have used a different folder. My codebase is not inside wwwroot folder of inetpub.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Applicationpool name is same as the site name. I have attached an image link above of the code snippet causing the issue.

Comment: What for a path have you configured in the „openToFile“ function?

Comment: I have used `$path =  storage_path("app/public/files"); $writer->openToFile($path."/".$filename)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** AT LAST GOT THE SOLUTION AFTER GOING THROUGH ANSWERS OF OTHER QUESTIONS RELATED TO THIS PROBLEM **

You can follow the following procedure:

- Go to **IIS Manager**
- Select your desired project (For example: myexampledomain.com) **listed under Sites**
- Go to **Security** tab and you'll see the users listed with their permissions on the folder.
- Now, click **Edit** button to go to a new window and click **Add**. In the text box,type `IIS AppPool\MyApplicationPoolName`.In our example it should be `IIS AppPool\myexampledomain.com`.
- Click **Check Name** and you'll see the test change with underline.
- Click **Ok**. Add the appropriate permission(Modify,read,write) to the newly created user.

That's it!!!

Thanks to all for responding.